# "both the users" or "the both users"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order, determiners, quantifiers

I keep running into this debate with my thesis advisor. Are both of these forms correct?

> It can be seen that *both the* users
>   are able to...

or

> It can be seen that *the both* users
>   are able to...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"The both users" is incorrect. The determiner *both* has already qualified *users*, so you know who is being referred to.  (Refer also to [this excellent answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/121285/5578).)  Adding *the* onto that is similar to saying "the the users".  People sometimes do this anyway, such as in the phrase "the both of them", but it's informal.

On the other hand, "both the users" is short for "both of the users".  The *of* is just elided.  I would think this is common enough to be acceptable.  But if you're in doubt, either use "both of the users" or, as MikeVaughan suggests, "both users".

Answer (score 12):

I think that the article ***the*** is extraneous.

> It can be seen that both users are able to...

is just fine.

Answer (score 4):

The first example is grammatically correct, the second example is not.

The first sentence in the "Article" wikipedia page says it better than I can: "An article (abbreviated art) is a word that combines with a noun to indicate the type of reference being made by the noun."

[Articles Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29)

Comment: I don't disagree, but can you explain why "the" is combined with "both"?  As a random example, in "the brown cow" `the` modifies `cow`, not `brown`, even though `brown` is the next word.

Comment: Despite my best efforts, I cannot. Let me retract that last sentence until it can be better qualified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Longman says

• You use both or both of before a determiner such as ‘the’, ‘these’, or ‘my’: Both (of) the women were tall.Both (of) her parents are dead. ✗ Don’t say: the both women | her both parents

Answer (score -1):

You could also say "It can be seen that *the two users* are able to..." or "It can be seen that *each user is* able to..."

**OT:** The real reason that I answer is to object to the weasel-phrase "It can be seen that..."

Can you find a less officious, less self-protective intro? Like "Notice that each user..." or "We see that both users are able..."

Simpler and plainer is better.

Comment: Third-person passive voice is often the norm in the type of writing it sounds like the OP is doing.  I don't much like it either, but it's also not part of the question.